# Retaining values of TextBox control I've programmatically created in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, return-value

I've been struggling this for a couple of hours now and can't seem to find the answer online. Several practices I've found online haven't done the job so I guess I'm doing something wrong.

I created a Table object, placed several TableRow objects under which I've placed TableCell. One column of this table consists of TextBox objects I've created:

```
Table productTable = new Table();
int j = 0;
foreach (Product i in prodList)
        {
            TextBox qttyTB = new TextBox();
            qttyTB.ID = "Quantity" + Convert.ToString(j);
            qttyTB.Style["width"] = "30px";
            qttyTB.Text = "0";
            TableRow tableR = new TableRow();
            TableCell tableC1 = new TableCell();
            tableC1.Text = "<img src='" + i.ImagePath + "' class='ProductImage'/>";
            tableR.Controls.Add(tableC1);
            TableCell tableC2 = new TableCell();
            tableC2.Text = i.Name + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            tableR.Controls.Add(tableC2);
            TableCell tableC3 = new TableCell();
            tableC3.Text = i.Price + "&nbsp;&#8362;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            tableR.Controls.Add(tableC3);
            TableCell tableC4 = new TableCell();
            tableC4.Controls.Add(tbArray[j - 1]);
            tableR.Controls.Add(tableC4);
            productTable.Controls.Add(tableR);
            j++;
        }
TablePH.Controls.Add(productTable);
```

The page output works 100%. Now, upon a button click I'm trying to retain the values of the TextBox objects I've created. Tried several things.

Comment: are you using Web Forms and leveraging ViewState?  Dynamically added controls need a bit more work - see [this article](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx).

Comment: why cant you populate a datatable and keep it in a session or so,you can bind that to a gridview which is a table in fact.

Comment: In which page event You call the code You've posted? You should add dynamically created controls in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load` page event.

Comment: Lukasz - I call this method upon Page_Load;
The difficulties I'm having is accessing the "Controls hierarchy".
Page -> Form -> Table -> TableRow -> TableCell -> TextBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Populating tables in CodeBehind is in general a bad practice and should be avoided because you are seperating View and Business logic concerns.

If you are retrieving the products from a database then you want to put something like this on your .aspx file. If not SQL then there are other DataSources that you can find by googling.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SelectItemsDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:hubConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:hubConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT itemEntity.id, itemEntity.name, itemEntity.filename, itemEntity.type, itemEntity.added, userEntity.name FROM item AS itemEntity 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN USER AS userEntity ON itemEntity.uploader = userEntity.id WHERE itemEntity.type like @type ORDER BY itemEntity.added DESC" 
        OnSelecting="onItemSelecting"> 
        <SelectParameters>
           <asp:Parameter Name="@type" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>       
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then where you define your Table you add different types of fields depending on what you want. NOTE: The attribute values which are surrounded by <%# x %> are calling a function in the codebehind.

```
<asp:GridView ID="ItemGrid" runat="server" DataSourceID="SelectItemsDataSource" class="itemGrid"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File type">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image runat="server" ID="mediaImage"
                    ImageUrl='<%# GetImageUrl(Eval("type") as string) %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a runat="server" id="mediaPreview" href='<%# GetPreviewUrl(Eval("id").ToString()) %>'>Play</a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="name" DataNavigateUrlFields="id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Download.aspx?FileID={0}" HeaderText="Name"/>            
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Uploaded date" 
            DataField="added" DataFormatString="{0:d MMMM, yyyy}" SortExpression="added">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Uploaded by" 
            DataField="name1" SortExpression="name1">
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```